# Intermittent hang during periodic update using WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am developing an application using WPF MVVM.
My program needs to quickly update a lot of data and display it in the UI.
I have a function that reads 2000 data from shared memory every 1millisecond and updates the UI.
At this time, there is a phenomenon that the data update is temporarily stopped every 2-3 seconds.
There was no stopping when updating from code behind without using MVVM.
To improve this phenomenon, the update cycle was changed to 100 milliseconds, but the freeze did not improve.
If you have experienced something like this, please share your solution with me.
The source code is a sample of the problem from my product.
Thank you very much.

View

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingHang.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingHang.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Changes1}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="100" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Changes2}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="100" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Changes3}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="100" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Changes4}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="100" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Changes5}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="100" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Changes6}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="100" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Changes7}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="100" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Changes8}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="100" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel

```
using BindingHang.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace BindingHang.ViewModels
{
    public class MainVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region << Fields >>
        private readonly int _maxCount = 1000;
        private readonly int _delay = 20;
        #endregion

        #region << Constructor >>
        public MainVM()
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        #endregion

        #region << Properties >>
        private readonly List<ChangeModel> _changes = new List<ChangeModel>();
        public IEnumerable<ChangeModel> Changes1 => _changes.Skip((int)(_maxCount / 8) * 0).Take((int)(_maxCount / 8));

        public IEnumerable<ChangeModel> Changes2 => _changes.Skip((int)(_maxCount / 8) * 1).Take((int)(_maxCount / 8));

        public IEnumerable<ChangeModel> Changes3 => _changes.Skip((int)(_maxCount / 8) * 2).Take((int)(_maxCount / 8));

        public IEnumerable<ChangeModel> Changes4 => _changes.Skip((int)(_maxCount / 8) * 3).Take((int)(_maxCount / 8));

        public IEnumerable<ChangeModel> Changes5 => _changes.Skip((int)(_maxCount / 8) * 4).Take((int)(_maxCount / 8));

        public IEnumerable<ChangeModel> Changes6 => _changes.Skip((int)(_maxCount / 8) * 5).Take((int)(_maxCount / 8));

        public IEnumerable<ChangeModel> Changes7 => _changes.Skip((int)(_maxCount / 8) * 6).Take((int)(_maxCount / 8));

        public IEnumerable<ChangeModel> Changes8 => _changes.Skip((int)(_maxCount / 8) * 7).Take((int)(_maxCount / 8));
        #endregion

        #region << Methods >>
        private void Initialize()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= _maxCount; i++)
            {
                _changes.Add(new ChangeModel
                {
                    Name = "Item " + i,
                    Value = i
                });
            }

            Routine();
        }

        private void Routine()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    foreach (var change in _changes)
                    {
                        _ = Application.Current?.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => change.ChangeValue()));
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(_delay);
                }
            });
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Model

```
using BindingHang.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace BindingHang.Models
{
    public class ChangeModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region << Fields >>
        private readonly double _minValue = 0;
        private readonly double _maxValue = 10000;
        private bool _direction = false;
        #endregion

        #region << Constructor >>
        public ChangeModel()
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region << Properties >>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        private double _value = 0;
        public double Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set => SetValue(ref _value, value);
        }
        #endregion

        #region << Methods >>
        public void ChangeValue()
        {
            if (Value == _minValue)
                _direction = true;
            else if (Value == _maxValue)
                _direction = false;

            double temp = Value;
            if (_direction)
                temp++;
            else
                temp--;

            Value = temp;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: No human being can or wants to track updates in milliseconds.

Comment: What I want is to optimize the real-time changing data so that it looks smooth to the user. I'm not sticking with 1 millisecond updates.

Comment: You should favor Dispatcher.InvokeAsync over Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. You should not execute the change.ChangeValue() on a background thread as you immediately delegate all work back to the main thread (by using the Dispatcher). Consider to use Parallel.ForEach and to convert Routine() to an async method (to await Task.Delay). Side note: handlers attached to the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event are always executed on the main thread as the binding engine marshals this event. This means the Dispatcher invocation to execute property changes is redundant.